# How do I enable my custom format for enter_bug.cgi?

Tags: bugzilla

I have followed the instructions in the Bugzilla manual and have created and tested my own custom format for enter_bug.cgi.  I have tested by manually entering "format=xxx" in the URL.  Now I am ready to roll this out for the other users.  What is the right way to enable my custom format as the default?

I have come up with a few solutions that seem not-so-nice to me:

1. Hack choose-classification.html.tmpl or choose-product.html.tmpl to force the format
2. Replace the existing create.html.tmpl with my custom version
3. Hack common-links.html.tmpl to force the format

It seems that the choose-classification.html.tmpl and choose-product.html.tmpl are already setup to properly handle a format variable that is passed in, but I can't seem to figure out the appropriate place to set that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted this question to the official bugzilla support news group (mozilla.support.bugzilla) and got only one response:

> if I were you, I'd name it template/en/custom/bug/create/create.html.tmpl so that it
>   overrides the default.

I didn't want to have my custom format used for every classification, so instead, I just modified choose-classification.html.tmpl to manually force the "format=xxx" into the URL for the classification to which the format applies.  Not the most elegant solution, but it works.